# Shortcut for Capitalizing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I want a shortcut for capitalize (change first letter of every word to upper case) in Android studio.

I know that *Toggle Case* shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> on Mac) in Android Studio.

I want a shortcut for capitalize just first letter of all words... it would be very useful for Javadocs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use **String Manipulation** plugin:

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=2162

it supports **Capitalize selected text**.

When you install this plugin, you can select your text and use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to open String Manipulation menu.